# Keep application active after the screen is turned off

Tags: android

I have a receiver in my app (public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver) which works just fine - except when the screen turns off. After the screen has turned off, the receiver stops receiving SMSes. Is there any way to solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you will have to start a service that will listen for these Broadcasts.  this is what I am doing while listening for ON_TIMETICK, SCREEN_OFF, and SCREEN_ON.  I could not get it to work any other way.